# jquery ui: ajax page + slider content

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, slider

I want to make a content slider similar to this [site](http://www.pentagram.com), but a bit simpler.

[This](http://lauthiamkok.net/dump/2011/jquery.slider/2/slide_2.2.php) is what I came out with so far. But I am stuck:

1.
I want to change the position of the slider handle when an ajax page is loaded. the width of `#content-holder` should be extended when the ajax page is loaded, from 1500px to 2000px (depends on how big the ajax page is).

2.
the `#content-holder` should slide to the left when the ajax page is load so that this ajax page will always visible when it is loaded.

3.
  when the ajax page is closed. the
    slider handle should go back to the
    original position. and the width of
    `#content-holder` should be contracted
    back to the original (1500px).

You can read the code in my jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/lauthiamkok/K8qgn/).

Any ideas how I can achieve these 3 points?

Thanks.

Comment: so you have the slider part working correctly and just need help with the formatting part once the ajax request loads and is closed?