# jquery ui: ajax page + slider content (part2)

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, slider

Following up on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738944/jquery-ui-ajax-page-slider-content) I made earlier. I have found out the answers for all the points. But I still have a small tweek that I cannot get it right -

That is the percentage value that I need to pass it into the slider -

```
var percentage = Math.round(offset.left / (scrollContent.width() - scrollPane.width()) * 100);
scrollbar.slider("value",percentage);
```

The percentage should increase everytime when I move the slider handle to the right. It is fine when I load the first two ajax pages (the percentage increases), but after these first two, the percentage starts dropping down until negative values.

How can I find the correct percentage?

You can try it out [here](http://lauthiamkok.net/dump/2011/jquery.slider/2/slide_2.2.php) and see what I mean above.

Below is the entire jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    loadSlide ();

});


function loadSlide ()
{
    //scrollpane parts
    scrollPane = $('#scroll-pane'); // scroll-pane
    scrollContent = $('#scroll-content'); // scroll-content

    //alert(scrollContent.width());

  scrollbar = $("#content-slider").slider({
    min: 0,
    create: loadContent,
    animate: true,
    change: handleSliderChange,
    slide: handleSliderSlide
  });
}

function handleSliderChange(event, ui)
{

  var maxScroll = scrollContent.width() - scrollPane.width();
  scrollPane.animate({scrollLeft: ui.value * (maxScroll / 100) }, 1000);

}

function handleSliderSlide(event, ui)
{

  var maxScroll = scrollContent.width() - scrollPane.width();
  scrollPane.attr({scrollLeft: ui.value * (maxScroll / 100) });

}

function loadContent(event, ui) 
{
    $('.load-content').click(function(){

        var path = $(this).attr('href');
        var parent = $(this).parents('.content-item');

        parent.after('<div class="wrapper"></div>');

        var target = $('.wrapper').css({float:'left'});
        target.load(path, function(){

            var width_loaded_content = target.width();
            var offset = target.offset();
            var position = target.position();
            scrollContent.css({width: (scrollContent.width() + width_loaded_content) + 'px'});

            var percentage = Math.round(offset.left / (scrollContent.width() - scrollPane.width()) * 100);
            alert(percentage);
            scrollbar.slider("value",percentage);

            exitContent (target);
        });

        return false;
    });
}

function exitContent (target)
{
    $('.exit-content').click(function(){
        scrollbar.slider("value",0);
        scrollContent.css({width: (1500) + 'px'});
        target.remove();
        return false;
    });
}
```

Another issue is, whey it sometimes alerts twice after the ajax pages is loaded but sometimes it does not? it should always alert once.

Any idea?